# A multistep Implicit Method for an ODE with a variable time step

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**The Problem:**

I want to solve the system of differential equations

$$
\frac{d \vec{\bf x}}{d t}=\matrix{\bf A}\vec{\bf x}+\vec{\bf b}\hspace{1 in} [\text{Eq}. 1]
$$

subject to a known initial condition, and where $\matrix{\bf A}$ is a sparse matrix.  In order to exploit a larger time step without sacrificing accuracy, I'd like to implement an implicit multi-step method, while also using a continuously increasing time step according to a prescribed schedule. Most of the methods in the literature are for a fixed time step and would not be applicable to my problem. So what I thought I'd do is expand the state vectors at the preceding 4 time instants in a Taylor's series about the current time by defining $\Delta t_k = t_n -t_{n-k}$ so that we have

$$
\vec{\bf x}_{n-k}=\vec{\bf x}_{n}-{\Delta t}_k \frac{d \vec{\bf x}}{d t}\Bigg|_{t_n}
+\frac{1}{2}{{\Delta t}_k}^2 \frac{d^2 \vec{\bf x}}{d t^2}\Bigg|_{t_n}
-\frac{1}{6}{{\Delta t}_k}^3 \frac{d^3 \vec{\bf x}}{d t^3}\Bigg|_{t_n}
+\frac{1}{24}{{\Delta t}_k}^4 \frac{d^4 \vec{\bf x}}{d t^4}\Bigg|_{t_n} + {O}({\Delta t}_k^5)\hspace{1 in} [\text{Eq}. 2]
$$

for $k=1\cdots 4$ and then invert the resulting $4 \times 4$ system so that I get the first derivative (the only derivative of interest to me) according to

$$
\frac{d \vec{\bf x}}{d t}=-\Bigg[\sum_{k=1}^4\beta_k\Bigg]\vec{\bf x}_n
+\sum_{k=1}^4\beta_k\vec{\bf x}_{n-k}\hspace{1 in} [\text{Eq}. 3]
$$

where for $\beta_k, k=1\cdots 4$ are the elements of the first row of the inverse of the $4 \times 4$ matrix of coefficients of the derivatives in the Taylor Series expansion. Substituting Eq. 1 in Eq. 3 results in the sparse linear system

$$
\matrix{\bf A'}\vec{\bf x}+\vec{\bf b'}\hspace{1 in} [\text{Eq}. 4]
$$

where

$$
\matrix{\bf A'}=\matrix{\bf A}+\lambda\matrix{\bf I}
$$

where

$$\lambda=\sum_{k=1}^4\beta_k \hspace{1 in} [\text{Eq}. 5]$$

and

$$
\vec{\bf b'}=-\vec{\bf b}+\sum_{k=1}^4\beta_k\vec{\bf x}_{n-k}
$$

I can solve the system in Eq. 4 using a stabilised pre-conditioned conjugate gradient algorithm. I have that part all very nicely figured out, and it works very well with the simple backward Euler scheme that I have currently implemented, but I am time-step restricted on the grounds of accuracy, not stability.

**My questions**

1. Before I go crazy with coding and implementation, is the multistep method described above an efficient approach to solving the problem? What are the pitfalls if any?
2. Owing to the computational stencil used to generate the matrix $\matrix{\bf A}$, the diagonal dominance (and hence stability) of the method requires that the sum of the $\beta_k$ terms in Eq. 5 above be $<0$. I don't see how this is provable.
3. The Adams Moulton method uses the interpolating polynomial approach that would be a bit tedious with a variable step size. Is the tedium worth the effort?!

Many thanks in advance.